# Disk Backed Image Cache for UIImageView in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I'm looking to swap out the `AFImageCache` used by default in the `UIImageView+AFNetworking` category for something that's disk based and that can managed a little more accurately (something like [NSURLCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). Unfortunately, since `UIImageView+AFNetworking` is a category and not a subclass, I can't just override [af_sharedImageCache](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m#L70) with a sublclass of `UIImageView` OR another category.

Is there any other way to achieve this functionality without copying and pasting most of `UIImageView+AFNetworking` into my own subclass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) project provides a similar UIImageView category, but offers both in-memory (using NSCache) and on-disk (using NSFileManager) caching.  I'd recommend just using that when you need to cache to disk.

The downside to this implementation is that your network requests won't go through your `AFHTTPClient` subclass, so depending on what your needs are you might need to implement your own operation queue, authentication, etc.  If you're just using it for something basic, like displaying avatar images in a table view, it should be fine.

If that downside bothers you, an alternate idea would be to use `SDImageCache` (included in the `SDWebImage` project) to cache the images, and download them yourself using AFNetworking.

Finally, note that AFNetworking has built-in support for `NSURLCache`, and if you create one it will cache your images to disk.  However, image caching is typically used for showing lots of images in a `UIScrollView`, and `NSURLCache` doesn't have good enough performance for smooth scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll definitely take a closer look at SDWebImage. Out of curiosity, why does NSURLCache have suboptimal performance? I was under the impression it used both memory and disk caching kind of like an L1 and L2 cache where the web request itself would be L3, which would in theory be pretty speedy.

Comment: This is a good explaination: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/wiki/How-is-SDWebImage-better-than-X%3F

Answer (score 2):

I have a fork of AFNetworking that includes file cache in the NSCachesDirectory.

You can find it here: https://github.com/andyast/AFNetworking_FileCache
There is a branch that is compatible with V1.3.3 if you need that as well.

Comment: Cool, works, would be best if AfNetworking works this way !!! Is it hard to modify directly latest AfNetworking ?